# Apex - Salesforce - Maps

Tags: list, dictionary, salesforce, apex-code

**Hello Folks**

I have a small query regarding Maps in Apex. I have a map `map <String, list <Account>>`. I am trying to do the following -

**What needs to be done**: I am passing a key to string variable and then passing that string to a Map.get() method to get the values for that key. Here, it does not give me the right answer. Even when I print out the Map using System.Debug() it prints out the map very differently!

```
String Id = 'Some Id that is the key in the map';
List <Account> testList = Map.get(Id);
```

This does not give me the corresponding value and I do not know why!

**BUT**

when I type the below code, the values are printed out perfectly.

```
for(String s : Map.keySet()){
   List <Account> TestList = Map.get(s);
   System.Debug('TestList' + TestList);
}
```

The Test list actually prints out what it is supposed to print out i.e. for each key it prints out the values where as when I print the map it does not print out as expected.

**What is expected**: I want to pass a key to the Map.get() method to retrieve the results but its clearly not happening in my case.

Any kinds of help is really appreciated!

Comment: In the first bit of code does your Map.get(Id) return anything or just null?

Comment: @SMGoodyear It just returns null.

Comment: OK cool. I notice you refer to the key as Id in a few places are you using Salesforce Ids in the key set or is it another form of Id? I only ask because I'm wondering if it's SF ids and you're storing them as strings you might be having issues with the 15 vs 18 character representation of the id. This is a complete stab in the dark by the way. If this isn't the case then we'll have to come up with another possibility - but always good to get the obvious ones out of the way first.

Comment: The other common gotcha with maps (I have literally just fallen foul of this) is that the get method is case sensitive.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the real full code that is failing. There isn't any bug in the get() method that would cause this; the bug is most likely that what you are passing to get() isn't exactly what is stored in the keyset. So showing us how the map is populated, and the actual ID you are passing in and the actual keys of the map, would inform an answer.

Comment: I think @SMGoodyear is correct, its most probably 15 vs 18 digit thing with IDs being used as KEY in MAP.

Comment: One thing I can suggest is to verify code which put everything into map and other thing - code which gets things from it. Maybe there is an issue in one of this parts of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two things I can think of here are:

- It's a case issue. To verify, convert your keys to uppercase:

> theMap.put(stringKey.toUpperCase(), theAccountList);

- By using Id as a variable name (itself a type), you are getting strange results

As others have already mentioned here, please post the actual code segment so we can help further or close this issue.

Thanks